# Cassandra two nodes with redundancy

Tags: cassandra

I have setup two servers to both run Cassandra by following the documentation in the DataStax website. My current setup is to have

> 1 seed node (configured in both yamls)

When running, both nodes are up (when testing via nodetool) and both seem to have the data replicated correctly but I've noticed that when I bring down the seed node, the other node doesn't allow client connections (neither via their API or by connecting to cqlsh) which is a problem.

My requirement is to have two servers which are perfect replicas of each other and in case one server is temporary down (due to disk space failures for instance), the other server can take over the requests until the broken server comes back online.

Given this requriement, I have the following questions:

1. Do I need to setup both nodes as "seed" nodes?
2. How would I make sure everything is replicated across both servers? Does this happen automatically or is there some setting somewhere I need to set?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cassandra does not do master-slave replication. There is no master in cassandra. Rather, data is distributed across the cluster. The distribution mechanism depends on a number of things.

Data is stored on nodes in partitions. Remember cassandra is a partitioned row store? That's where partitions come in. Data is stored in partitions. All rows for a partition are stored together in a single node (and replicas). How many replicas depends on the table's replication factor. If the replication factor is 3 for a table, each partition for that table (and as such, all rows in that partition) are stored in two additional replicas. It's like saying - "I want 3 copies of this data".

During writing, clients can specify a consistency level (CL). This is the number of nodes that must acknowledge for a write to be successful. Clients can specify a CL for reading too. Cassandra issues read requests to n=CL nodes, and takes the most recent value as the query result.

By tuning read and write CLs, you control consistency. If Read CL + Write CL > Replication factor (RF), you get full consistency.

In terms of fault tolerance, you can tweak CLs and RF to be what you need. For example, if you have RF=3, Read CL=2, Write CL = 2, then you have full consistency, and you can tolerate one node going down. For RF=5, Read CL=3, Write CL=3, you have the same, but can tolerate 2 nodes going down.

A two node cluster, is not really a good idea. You can set RF=2 (all data replicated), write CL=2 and read CL =1. However, this will mean if a node is down, you can only read but not write. You can set read CL=2 and write CL=1, in which case, if a node goes down, you can write but not read. Realistically, you should go for at least 5 (at the very least 4) nodes with a RF=3. Any lower than that, and you're asking for trouble.

Comment: I should add that with 2 nodes, you CAN do RF=2, Read CL=1 and Write CL = 1; however, that would mean that you may be reading stale data until it's been replicated to the other node. It'll allow you to read and write if only one node is live, but you're sacrificing consistency.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Great explanation. One last question, if I were to choose to have 2 nodes with Read/Write CL=1 (I know it's not good but I only have 2 servers at my disposal in my Beta stage and will only be able to add more servers later on), would I need to set both nodes as "seeds" so that in case one node/server goes down, connection is still possible?

Comment: Seeds aren't *that* critical. It's the address you give to clients assuming that the seed nodes will be stable. The client will connect to a seed, and get info about the rest of the cluster. It would then connect to any node in the cluster for transactions. If you don't specify seeds, the information might propagate anyway through gossip. If you tell your client to connect to a non-seed, it shouldn't really cause an issue for your two node setup. If you mark both as seeds, if a client connects to one and it's down, it'll connect to the other. I'd mark them both as seeds.

Comment: @ashic I have 2-node cluster, RF = 2, Read CL = 1, Write CL = 1. If a node (let say node 2) goes down, the cluster can still receive data from clients (on node 1). However, at that time the number of replicas created is 1, is this right? After that, if the node 2 becomes up, is there any ways that the data on node 1 is replicated to node 2 automatically?

Comment: Long delay..missed it :) If you run a repair (which you should if the node's been down for > grace period or if it's a new node, it'll get replicated. Also, when queries for partitions execute, there's a 10% chance that it'll trigger a read repair, which would cause replication.

Comment: Can you please explain  "Any lower than that, and you're asking for trouble"? :) Why 5 is better than 3 provided that RF=3?